# ¿Cómo utilizar variables globales de tipo punteros en Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, variables-globales

Necesito crear una variable de tipo global para poder usar la misma en 2 acciones diferentes: cuando se abra la ventana y cuando presione un botón, sin embargo, no sé cómo utilizar esa misma variable pues la método de la ventana es uno y el de la acción del botón es otro. Adjunto código:

```
#include "produccion.h"
#include "ui_produccion.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include "structs.h"

Produccion::Produccion(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Produccion)
{
    /*Aquí es donde se abre la ventana*/
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ListaPaquetes *nuevoPaquete = new ListaPaquetes(); /*Esta es la que debo 
    usar mas abajo*/
    nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(4,"paquetito");
    nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(10,"paquete");
    nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(16,"tubo");
    QList<QString> tiposPaquetes = nuevoPaquete->paquetesAgregados();
    int ejex = 40;
    int ejey = 120;
    QString nombrePaquetito = tiposPaquetes.at(0);
    QString nombrePaquete = tiposPaquetes.at(1);
    QString nombreTubo = tiposPaquetes.at(2);
    ui->paquetitoLabel->setText("Cantidad de " + nombrePaquetito + "s: ");
    ui->paqueteLabel->setText("Cantidad de " + nombrePaquete + "s: ");
    ui->tuboLabel->setText("Cantidad de " + nombreTubo + "s: ");
    for (int i=3; i<tiposPaquetes.length();i++)
    {
        QString nombreBoton = tiposPaquetes.at(i) + "Label";
        QLabel *label;
        label = new QLabel("Cantidad de " + tiposPaquetes.at(i)+ "s: 
        ",this);
        label->setObjectName(nombreBoton);
        label->setGeometry(ejex,ejey,131,16);
        ejey += 30;
    }
}

Produccion::~Produccion()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Produccion::on_agregarPaquete_clicked()/*Esta es la accion del boton*/
{
    if (ui->nombrePaquete->text() == "")
    {
        if (ui->cantGalletas->value() == 0)
        {
            this->show();
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Debe introducir el nombre del 
            paquete y una cantidad");
        }
        else
        {
            this->show();
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Debe introducir el nombre del 
            paquete");
        }
    }
    else if (ui->cantGalletas->value() == 0)
    {
        this->show();
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Debe introducir una cantidad de 
        galletas");
    }
    else
    {
        QString nombreNuevoPaquete = "";
        int cantGalletasNuevo = 0;
        nombreNuevoPaquete = ui->nombrePaquete->text();
        cantGalletasNuevo = ui->cantGalletas->value();
        ListaPaquetes *nuevoPaquete = new ListaPaquetes();/*Aqui es donde 
        debo usarla de nuevo, la instancié pero ese hace una nueva, y debo 
        usar la pasada*/
        nuevoPaquete->crearPaquete(cantGalletasNuevo,nombreNuevoPaquete);
        QList<QString> tiposPaquetes = nuevoPaquete->paquetesAgregados();
        //Esto es solo para ver los paquetes de tiposPaquetes
        for (int i=0;i<tiposPaquetes.length();i++)
        {
            qDebug()<<tiposPaquetes.at(i);
        }
        this->close();
        Produccion *nuevaProduccion = new Produccion();
        nuevaProduccion->show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas variables globales. Basta con que sea una variable miembro de `Produccion`.

Declaración:

```
class Produccion
 : public QDialog /* o la herencia que corresponda */
{
private:

  ListaPaquetes nuevoPaquete;
};
```

Implementación:

```
Produccion::Produccion(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Produccion)
{
    // ...

    nuevoPaquete.crearPaquete(4,"paquetito");
    nuevoPaquete.crearPaquete(10,"paquete");
    nuevoPaquete.crearPaquete(16,"tubo");

    // ...
}

void Produccion::on_agregarPaquete_clicked()/*Esta es la accion del boton*/
{
    // ...

    nuevoPaquete.crearPaquete(cantGalletasNuevo,nombreNuevoPaquete);

    QList<QString> tiposPaquetes = nuevoPaquete.paquetesAgregados();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: La variable debe de ser de tipo puntero a ListaPaquetes, ¿o da lo mismo como lo estás implementando?

Comment: @FabricioCeciliano con el codigo que enseñas no es necesario usar punteros

Comment: Sé que no, pero para el desarrollo del programa me solicitan utilizar punteros

Comment: @FabricioCeciliano cambiarlo a punteros no es complicado... pero asegurate de llamar al delete correspondiente en el destructor